# Firebase error : ReferenceError: request is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this in my database:
[image]

When I try to query this on a Firebase cloud function:

```
databaseRef.child("users-locale/world").orderByKey().limitToFirst(10).once("value", (snapshot) => {
      // do something
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at databaseRef.child.orderByKey.startAt.limitToFirst.once (/user_code/index.js:48:81)
    at c (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:207:58)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:185:831
    at tc (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:77:165)
    at le (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:112:215)
    at me (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:111:632)
    at dh.h.Eb (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:241:287)
    at kh.h.ud (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:228:251)
    at hg.ud (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:175:364)
    at Pf.Xf (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:173:281)
```

Comment: share the full code,actually problem is in databaseref variable

Comment: Try using promises instead `once("value").then((snapshot) => {})`